# Don't understand the difference between variable declarations, symbols, methods, instance variables, class variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Updated this post as per post recommendations:
Inconsistent naming conventions in rails is confusing the heck out of me. IT SEEMS LIKE THE SYNTAX IS ALL OVER THE PLACE IN RAILS...

**Here are some examples:**

Why are there commas in the migration below ? And why is keyword "default" not with a colon before it? What is this default keyword? a method, or a variable, a symbol.. What is that darn thing??:

```
add_column :zombies, :rotting, :boolean, default: false
```

**Here is another example:**

Why age not :age (with a colon)? WHY IS make_rotting CALLED WITH A " **:** " BEFORE IT??

```
 class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
       before_save :make_rotting

   def make_rotting
      if age > 20
         self.rotting = true
      end
    end
 end
```

I am a Java guy, yes java is verbose but at-least its consistent I feel like going back :(

Comment: You should read a Ruby book/tutorial. It's important that you learn the basics of Ruby *before* Rails.

Comment: [Andrew's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/211563/andrew-marshall) advice is good, but also if you update the question with a few specific examples people may be able to offer more help.

Comment: I have updated the question with specific examples. It just seems like rails syntax is all over the place. I dont know when I am calling a method or referring to a symbol or some attribute. I get instance variable synatx which is easy. but all this colon and non colon inconsistency is mind boggling  ... Help

Comment: That's Ruby's syntax, not Rails'. Please read any intro ruby book, then a Rails book, then ask again (but you shouldn't have to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all there are different type of variable:

1.Local variable

```
foobar
```

2.Instance variable

```
@foobar
```

3.Class variable

```
@@foobar
```

4.Global variable

```
$foobar
```

You can simply differentiate among them by the way they are used.

Now if talk about property of a model,can declare as

```
property :foobar, :type => FIXNUM
```

Now `validate` and `validates` both are different

```
validates :foobar ,:numerically => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0}
```

where `validates` is use to validate properties.

```
validate :method_name
```

where `validate` is to validate some method

Answer (score 1):

Ruby and Rails can be very confusing in the beginning I agree.

I think you'll get a better answer if you provide code examples. Because you are a beginner and you might be misunderstanding `variable` for a method or `:value` for a key/symbol.

One thing I can help you with though:

`variable: :value` is actually

`key: :value` (where `:value` is a Symbol)

Ruby's new hash syntax which used to be:

`:key => :value`

Comment: The synonym would be `:key => :value`, actually.